# jquery get not working to populate a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click a button to get information from another page and then populate a text box and show that text box and hide the div above it, it doesn't work, the get is going to the link, Ive tried putting an alert in the `$.get(url,function(d){` but that doesn't alert, Here's my javascript:

```
<!-- edit a status !-->
$('.update_status').on('click', function(e){
    var theId = this.id;
    var url = '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/timeline_status/' + theId;
    $.get(url,function(d){
        $('.timeline_status').hide();
        $('.update_status_post').show();
        $('.update_status_post_text').val(d);
        },'json');
    }); 
<!-- End edit a status !-->


<a class="update_status" href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?php echo System::escape($status->timeline_status_id); ?>"><li class="fa fa-edit"></li></a>
```

Here's my html to iniate the javascript above:

```
        <!-- update post inputs !-->
        <div class="update_status_post" style="display:none;">
            <p>
                <form method="POST" action="<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>dashboard/update_status/<?php echo System::escape($status->timeline_status_id); ?>" class="update_status_form">
                    <textarea name="new_status" class="col-sm-12 update_status_post_text" rows="5"></textarea>
                    <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" name="submit" value="<?php echo System::translate("Update"); ?>"></p>
                </form>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- end update post inputs !-->
```

Here's what my network tab on chrome shows:

```
Remote Address:[::1]:80
Request URL:http://localhost/github/techDirectory/techDirectory/dashboard/timeline_status/58
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:9
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 25 Aug 2015 12:12:22 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=81
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.8
```

Comment: any error in the console ?

Comment: Add a sample return from AJAX.

Comment: So what is actually being returned? Add an error handler to the Ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Because expected return value is `JSON`, jquery will parse the return string to JSON. That value we get in the variable `d`. To change the JSON object to string use <kbd>[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)</kbd>.

```
$.get(url,function(d){
    $('.timeline_status').hide();
    $('.update_status_post').show();
    $('.update_status_post_text').val(JSON.stringify(d));
},'JSON');
```

**Solution 2**

Get make the datatype `text`.

```
$.get(url,function(d){
    $('.timeline_status').hide();
    $('.update_status_post').show();
    $('.update_status_post_text').val(d);
},'text');
```

Comment: the callback is not even firing, how this can solve something ?

Comment: @Hacketo  @randommman : how about making the datatype `text`?